# Using grid file transformation (.gsb) in QGIS 3.16.14

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ntv2-transformation, gridfile

In QGIS 3.16.14-Hannover。

I want to add new grid raster files *'Beta2007_Re.gsb'* (EPSG:31466 to EPSG:25832) in QGIS. I used the following way in QGIS 3.16.14, which i have used in QGIS 3.10.5:

1. Put *'Beta2007_Re.gsb'* into `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.14\share\proj`
2. Edit `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.14\apps\qgis-ltr\resources\srs.db`

   ```
   UPDATE tbl_srs
   SET parameters ='+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +nadgrids=Beta2007_Re.gsb +units=m +no_defs'
   WHERE auth_id = 31466
   ```
3. Edit `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.14\apps\qgis-ltr\resources\srs.db`

   ```
   INSERT INTO tbl_datum_transform
   VALUES (
    99999,
    100099,
    4314,
    4528,
    9615,
    'Beta2007_Re.gsb', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    'amtliche Gitterdatei',
    'Für Genauigkeitsanforderungen im cm Bereich',
    1,
    0,
    NULL)
   ```
4. Edit `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.14\share\proj.db`

   ```
   INSERT INTO grid_transformation (
    auth_name,
    code,
    name,
    description,
    scope,
    method_auth_name,
    method_code,
    method_name,
    source_crs_auth_name,
    source_crs_code,
    target_crs_auth_name,
    target_crs_code,
    area_of_use_auth_name,
    area_of_use_code,
    accuracy,
    grid_param_auth_name,
    grid_param_code,
    grid_param_name,
    grid_name,
    grid2_param_auth_name,
    grid2_param_code,
    grid2_param_code,
    grid2_param_name,
    grid2_name,
    interpolation_crs_auth_name,
    interpolation_crs_code,
    operation_version,
    deprecated)
   SELECT
    auth_name,
    99999,
    'DHDN to ETR89 (Beta2007_Re.gsb)',
    'Transformation mit Gitterdatei Beta2007_Re',
    'Für Genauigkeiten im Zentimeterbereich',
    method_auth_name,
    method_code,
    method_name,
    source_crs_auth_name,
    source_crs_code,
    target_crs_auth_name,
    target_crs_code,
    area_of_use_auth_name,
    area_of_use_code,
    0.1,
    grid_param_auth_name,
    grid_param_code,
    grid_param_name,
    'Beta2007_Re.gsb',
    grid2_param_auth_name,
    grid2_param_code,
    grid2_param_code,
    grid2_param_name,
    grid2_name,
    interpolation_crs_auth_name,
    interpolation_crs_code,
    operation_version,
    deprecated
   FROM grid_transformation
   WHERE code = 15948
   ```

But in the end, I can't see it in Default Datum Transformations.